# How to use flex-container

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a custom `Date picker` in Angular. I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ovamx9ePIuE) YouTube tutorial. I read [Complete guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) also. The tutor straightaway started using `flex-container` in his `HTML` code. No bootstrap nothing. Anyway, I followed him exactly. The output that He's getting on his screen is:

[image: a perfect calendar].

But I'm not getting any grid like structure. For me it is:
[image]

Here is my HTML code **app.component.html**:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background: #d3d3d3;
}

a.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

#calendar-container {
  width: 462px;
}

.calendar-days {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background: #669999;
  border: 3px solid #c2c2c2;
}

.inactive {
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container flex-center">
  <div id="calendar-container" class="flex-container flex-column flex-center">
    <div class="flex-container flex-center-horz">
      <div>
        November
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-container">
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Sun</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Mon</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Tue</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Wed</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Thu</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Fri</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Sat</div>
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center">Sun</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-container flex-wrap">
    <div *ngFor="let day of daysArr">
      <div class="calendar-days flex-container flex-center" [ngClass]="{'inactive': !day}">{{day}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not able to figure out what's wrong with my code. I tried this on `Chrome`, `Firefox` and `IE` but same results. Please correct me.

Comment: The `flex-container` class does nothing without some corresponding CSS, I imagine the guide is using an existing stylesheet/library that has those classes pre-styled.

Comment: @DBS, He didn't say anything about any other `css`. He right away started using `flex-containers` without telling how and why.

Comment: @Quentin, Ok Sir. I'll search some other videos then.

Comment: @Quentin. I'm not good at css. I thought `flex-container` is some keyword and will take everything automatically.

Comment: It's a class name. There's nothing special about **any** class name. @DBS already told you that.

Comment: You should be learning basic CSS, before moving onto flexbox. The guide you linked in our question covers flexbox pretty well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex box is useful but not easy to understand. However, if you start understanding it, you would find it powerful. 
To use flex box, you should specify flex display in your css code, like `display: flex;`. That means the element is a flex box in which children can auto fill it or change their size. 
To make the children's width/height auto-change, you have to specify the flex weight in its css code, like `flex: 1` besides `display: flex`.
For example, in your code, let's make `flex-container` a flex box, we decorate it with `display: flex;`

```
.flex-container{
    display: flex;
    width: 500px; /* specify box width, children could only fill at most this size */
}
.calendar-days{
    flex: 1;
}
```

Then, you would see, we have a container with `500px` container, and its children are fill on average.
[flex-example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPgRP.png)

NOTE: 
I think there are some other bugs in your code.
1. you add `flex-container` to all the parent and children. You'd better add `display:flex` to the container with variable size children elements. 
2. `React-native` (another js framework) use only flex box and we could produce a nice app with only flex box.

The complete code are posted here.(If you have any questions, just contact me)

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            background: #d3d3d3;
        }

        a.active {
            background-color: gray;
        }

        #calendar-container {
            width: 462px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        .flex-container{
            flex: 1;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
        }
        .calendar-days {
            width: 60px;
            height: 60px;
            background: #669999;
            border: 3px solid #c2c2c2;
            flex: 1;
        }

        .inactive {
            opacity: 0.6;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="flex-center">
        <div id="calendar-container" class="flex-container flex-column flex-center">
          <div class="flex-container flex-center-horz">
            <div>
              November     
            </div>
          </div>  
          <div class="flex-container">
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Sun</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Mon</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Tue</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Wed</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Thu</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Fri</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Sat</div>
            <div class="calendar-days flex-center">Sun</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CHANGELOG:

1. delete `flex-container` in class `calendar-days` elements
2. add `display:flex;` to `#calendar-container`;
   add `flex-direction: column;` to `#calendar-container`
   add `flex: 1` to `.flex-container`
   cause I want the flex-container to fill the remain region
3. add `display:flex;` to `.flex-container`
   add `flex-direction: row;` to `.flex-container`
   add `flex: 1` to `.calendar-days`
   cause I want the `.calendar-days` to fill the flex-container on average

UPDATED:

1. It seems that you are not very familiar with css, and that's the key problem. It is recommended you should learn some basic css & html first.
2. You mentioned the tutor did not use `flex` in his stylesheet and post a url. However, if you take a look at the whole structure of his app, you would see a package named `styles`. In that package, you may find what you want. The url is here https://github.com/Bigless27/date-range-picker/blob/master/src/styles/headings.css
3. If you decide to learn something about `flex`, concepts below is very basic concepts of flex layout.

   1. flex
   2. justify-content
   3. align-self
   4. flex-direction

Comment: But now I'm getting all the days from 0 to 30 in a single row.

Comment: I've edited my HTML code in the question. Please check my code now.

Comment: @Tanzeel I only showed one flex-container here. If you want a box to contain multipe flexible columns, then in the container, you should add `display: flex;`(default flex-direction is column). Besides, if you also want these flexible columns to contain flexible rows, then you should add `display: flex, flex-direction: row`. For each element you want to make it flexible, don't forget to add `flex: 1`(`flex: <Number>` is ok), which means how much space the element takes up. Also, It seems you did not add flex related css to your selector, is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You `flex-container` doesn't have any corresponding CSS. Try to write some CSS for it. Maybe start off with something like this :

```
.flex-container{
  display:flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

Comment: But the tutor is himself not using it. See his css: https://github.com/Bigless27/date-range-picker/blob/master/src/app/app.component.css

Comment: @Quentin. Oh God. This person didn't even mention anything about files. Just uploaded the video and wasted my entire day.

Comment: @Quentin totally agree with you on that one :)

Answer (score 0):

Add these codes to your CSS

```
.flex-container { display: flex; }
 .flex-center{
 align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
 }
 .flex-wrap{

  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .flex-center-horz{
 align-items:center
    justify-content:center;
 }
 .flex-column{
 flex-direction: column;

 }
```

You can search for every class of your divs.
Take a look at https://the-echoplex.net/flexyboxes/

[CSS3 flexbox layout max 3 child items on one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27783450/css3-flexbox-layout-max-3-child-items-on-one-line)